# itunes Connect not showing build

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have created new app on the app store and uploaded the first build through app loader.

Initially after successful upload, I got emails for issues in the app and I resolved them and uploaded again. This time i havent got any email and I thought it is successful, When I checked it on the ITunes connect then build was not available anywhere.

I googled lot and tried many optioned but still build is not appearing in the itunes connect.

Answer (score 2):

First time when you upload the build on iTunes it has to be added as:

> Version : 1.0   &   Build : 1.0 or 1

If Apple gives any issue in this version to resolve, then you will resolve them and upload a new build as:

> Version : 1.0   &   Build : 1.1 or 2

Build number should be incremental each time you submit the app to the store if Version number is same.

In the `iTunesConnect`, under the `Build` section, Remove the current version and add a latest uploaded version. This may take some time for the latest uploaded build to appear under the `Build` section in the `iTunesConnect`.

Comment: Thanks MilanG. I will try this and will update you. Actually when first version failed certification then I re-uploaded it as Version 2.0 and Build 2 and this way the last build I uploaded was 6 .

Comment: I have uploaded the new build with Version 1.0 and Build as 1. Upload is successful but after 30 minute also I am not seeing anything under build section. Under build section "Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later." this text is coming

Comment: Do you see 'Prepare for submission' with yellow dot in your iTunesConnect account? What iOS App version does it show? If it is showing iOS App 1.0 then go to Build section and see if it is showig + icon or any version? If not please help me know about it via uploading a screenshot.

Comment: This is what I am seeing [link](http://ainaa.org/upload/uploads/Dk.PNG)

Comment: I Uploaded a new minor version and now I am getting error in a mail as "Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file in ... " . I tried everything from internet and various forums to fix this but none of them working.